# img width and height attributes being set by get_the_post_thumbnail

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

I'm working on a custom theme that I've inherited to maintain. At the top of the homepage there is a header area with some images generated by `get_the_post_thumbnail`. The call to `get_the_post_thumbnail` outputs img objects that are set to a specific width/height by their html attributes. Here's the code and output:

**Inside a loop**

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, array( 300, 300 ) ); ?>
```

**Html output**

```
<img width="215" height="93" src="[img filepath]" class="attachment-300x300 wp-post-image" alt="[img name]" title="[img name]">
```

I need to reset the attribute height and width dimensions to something other than *215 x 93*. I can't find anywhere this is being set (checked in **wp-admin** as well as **functions.php** as well as anywhere else where I thought it might be). I am also not finding any places where `set_post_thumbnail_size` is being called with these values. Can anyone tell me where to reset these values?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the image larger than 215x93? WordPress will not embiggen a smaller image, to prevent the image from looking like crap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at adding an image size to your themes `functions.php` file.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

You then just need to do `<?php the_post_thumbnail('image-size-name'); ?>` and it will pull out the image based on the sizes you set.